# how to create an advanced html quiz

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on this quiz for days now. I have managed to create a quiz with solutions at the end, but I do not want that. I want the solutions to appear at the end of every wrong answer given by the user, and if the user is correct no answer should display,

```html
<HEAD>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.bgclr {background-color: white; color: black; font-weight: bold;}
-->
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">


// Insert scooter questions number of questions
var numQues = 5;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(5);

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = "Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.";
answers[1] = "Road which cross.";
answers[2] = "When a traffic officer order you to do so.";
answers[3] = "Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.";
answers[4] = "(i), (ii) and (iii)";
answers[5] = "A marked pedestrian crossing ahead.";


function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;
  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
  break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";
  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
  }
  
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
}
//  End -->
</script>

</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<BODY>

<h3>Scooter quiz by johnson</h3>

<form name="quiz">




1. Which rule is considered the most important RULE OF THE ROAD in South Africa?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.">Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Do not exceed the speed limit.">Do not exceed the speed limit.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.">Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.</li>
  
   
</ul>




2. Sign L9 warns you about... ahead.

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Where you are also not allowed to park."> Where you are also not allowed to park..</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>



3.Under what circumstances, if any, are you allowed to drive your motor motor vehicle on the right-hand side of a public road with traffic moving in both directions?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.">When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When a traffic officer order you to do so.">When a traffic officer order you to do so.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Under no circumstance.">Under no circumstance.</li>
</ul>



4.Sign CC9 is found at ..
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.">Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.">Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Sharp curve to the right.">Sharp curve to the right.</li>
</ul>

5.You may not obtain a learner’s license if...

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A first-aid post."> A first-aid post.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>








<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear answers">
<p> Score = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="5" name="percentage" disabled></strong><br><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea class="bgclr" name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="10" cols="100" disabled>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: where do you want them to show? it's not showing anything now

Comment: sorry about that, i just eddited the code on the question, i want the answers to appear at the end of the choices, if the user is wrong

Comment: do you want to put them inside `<textarea class="bgclr" name="solutions" ` ?

Comment: they are already there,i want them to appear at the end of the question,before the next quetion (if the user is wrong),

Comment: take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39982063/2545680)

Comment: thanks alot maximus that is very very helpful,is there away i can activate/show the correct answer after the user clicks  the GET SCORE button?

Comment: yeah. it'll update in a moment

Comment: I've updated my answer. Continue from there. Mark the answer as expected please if it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I've shown you how this can be done for the first block of questions. You can work from there.

```html
<HEAD>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.bgclr {background-color: white; color: black; font-weight: bold;}
-->

 .hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .visible {
  display: block;
 }
 
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">


// Insert scooter questions number of questions
var numQues = 5;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(5);

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = "Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.";
answers[1] = "Road which cross.";
answers[2] = "When a traffic officer order you to do so.";
answers[3] = "Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.";
answers[4] = "(i), (ii) and (iii)";
answers[5] = "A marked pedestrian crossing ahead.";


function getScore(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;
  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
  break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";
  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
  }
  
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var q1Inputs = document.querySelector('.q1-inputs');
 q1Inputs.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  if (event.target.value !== 'Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.') {
   q1Inputs.lastElementChild.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
   q1Inputs.lastElementChild.classList.add('hidden');
  }
 });
});

//  End -->
</script>

</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<BODY>

<h3>Scooter quiz by johnson</h3>

<form name="quiz">




1. Which rule is considered the most important RULE OF THE ROAD in South Africa?
<ul class="q1-inputs" style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.">Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Do not exceed the speed limit.">Do not exceed the speed limit.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.">Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.</li>
  <li class="hidden" style="color:red;">The correct answer is: Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.</li>
  
   
</ul>




2. Sign L9 warns you about... ahead.

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Where you are also not allowed to park."> Where you are also not allowed to park..</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>



3.Under what circumstances, if any, are you allowed to drive your motor motor vehicle on the right-hand side of a public road with traffic moving in both directions?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.">When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When a traffic officer order you to do so.">When a traffic officer order you to do so.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Under no circumstance.">Under no circumstance.</li>
</ul>



4.Sign CC9 is found at ..
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.">Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.">Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Sharp curve to the right.">Sharp curve to the right.</li>
</ul>

5.You may not obtain a learner’s license if...

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A first-aid post."> A first-aid post.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>








<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear answers">
<p> Score = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="5" name="percentage" disabled></strong><br><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea class="bgclr" name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="10" cols="100" disabled>
</textarea>
</form>
```

UPDATE:

```html
<HEAD>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
.bgclr {background-color: white; color: black; font-weight: bold;}
-->

 .hidden {
  display: none;
 }
 
 .visible {
  display: block;
 }
 
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">


// Insert scooter questions number of questions
var numQues = 5;

// Insert number of choices in each question
var numChoi = 3;

// Insert number of questions displayed in answer area
var answers = new Array(5);

// Insert answers to questions
answers[0] = "Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.";
answers[1] = "Road which cross.";
answers[2] = "When a traffic officer order you to do so.";
answers[3] = "Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.";
answers[4] = "(i), (ii) and (iii)";
answers[5] = "A marked pedestrian crossing ahead.";


function getScore(form) {
 showCorrectAnswers();

  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;
  for (i=0; i<numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i*numChoi;
    for (j=0; j<numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
  break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  score = Math.round(score/numQues*100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";
  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i=1; i<=numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + answers[i-1] + "\r\n";
  }
  
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
}

function showCorrectAnswers() {
 var q1Inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.q1-inputs input');
 var correctAnswer = document.querySelector('.q1-inputs span');
 var correct = correctAnswer.textContent;
 q1Inputs.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element.checked) {
   if (element.value !== correct) {
    correctAnswer.classList.remove('hidden');
   } else {
    correctAnswer.classList.add('hidden');
   }
  }
 });
}

//  End -->
</script>

</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document  -->

<BODY>

<h3>Scooter quiz by johnson</h3>

<form name="quiz">




1. Which rule is considered the most important RULE OF THE ROAD in South Africa?
<ul class="q1-inputs" style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.">Always be courteous and considerate towards fellow road users.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Do not exceed the speed limit.">Do not exceed the speed limit.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q1" value="Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.">Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.</li>
  <span class="hidden" style="color:red;">Keep to the left side of the road far as is safe.</span>
  
   
</ul>




2. Sign L9 warns you about... ahead.

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Where you are also not allowed to park."> Where you are also not allowed to park..</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q2" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>



3.Under what circumstances, if any, are you allowed to drive your motor motor vehicle on the right-hand side of a public road with traffic moving in both directions?
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.">When you switch the emergency lights of your vehicle on.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="When a traffic officer order you to do so.">When a traffic officer order you to do so.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q3" value="Under no circumstance.">Under no circumstance.</li>
</ul>



4.Sign CC9 is found at ..
<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.">Traffic circle where right of way is applicable.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.">Dangerous place where roadwork is being done.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q4" value="Sharp curve to the right.">Sharp curve to the right.</li>
</ul>

5.You may not obtain a learner’s license if...

<ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A first-aid post."> A first-aid post.</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="A railway crossing">A railway crossing</li>
  <li><input type="radio" name="q5" value="Road which cross">Road which cross</li>
</ul>








<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getScore(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear answers">
<p> Score = <strong><input class="bgclr" type="text" size="5" name="percentage" disabled></strong><br><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea class="bgclr" name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="10" cols="100" disabled>
</textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: This is nice, but did OP want the answers to appear on submit rather than on change?

Comment: it's not easy to understand what the OP wants :). I haven't seen any `submit` in the code. Anyways, it's easy to modify the code a bit

Comment: thanks alot maximus that is very very helpful,is there away i can activate/show the correct answer after the user clicks the GET SCORE button?

Comment: @Maximus I agree that this is the correct approach, just handle on button click and show corrected answers. Also, `submit` was a poor word choice on my part. Should have been `click`

Comment: @mhatch i gree with you guys, but i do not want the user to see the answers before they finish the quiz

Comment: @MbaliNtuli That is what we are talking about. Change the event handler to the button click, then loop through the questions/answers and  implement the `.remove('hidden')`

Comment: you see @mhatch that i do not know how to do,

Comment: You should be able to look that up and finish it. Steps are: 1. add hidden `<li>` element to store the correct answer (this can be done manually or with js), 2. create a handler for button click, 3. inside handler loop through questions and check if answer is correct, 4. if answer is incorrect remove hidden class from answer `<li>` element.

Comment: Alternatively, if you do not want to have the answer elements hidden, you could append the `<li>` element to the question `<ul>` when the loop check evaluates to an incorrect answer.

Comment: @mhatch, yeah, that's a good option as well. I prefer to keep elements in the DOM and show/hide them when needed. I think this is OP's home work :). He'll still have to finish it with other answers. I showed how it can be done only for the first one

Comment: guys thank you so so so so so much,i do not know what to say say really, thank you.

Comment: @MbaliNtuli, you can accept the answer :)

Comment: at maximus function showCorrectAnswerss() {
 var q2Inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.q2-inputs input');
 var correctAnswer2 = document.querySelector('.q2-inputs span');
 var correct2 = correctAnswer2.textContent;
 q2Inputs.forEach(function(element1) {
  if (element1.checked) {
   if (element.value !== correct2) {
    correctAnswer2.classList.remove('hidden2');
   } else {
    correctAnswer2.classList.add('hidden2');
   }
  }
 });

Comment: @MbaliNtuli, have you considered [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) ?

Comment: @Maximus i will accept the answer as soon as i can, the question has been placed on hold

Comment: @Maximus i tried moddifying your answer so that i cn add solutions to ather questions but it doesnt work this is the fuction i added on the javascript section

Comment: function showCorrectAnswerss() {
 var q2Inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.q2-inputs input');
 var correctAnswer2 = document.querySelector('.q2-inputs span');
 var correct2 = correctAnswer2.textContent;
 q2Inputs.forEach(function(element1) {
  if (element1.checked) {
   if (element.value !== correct2) {
    correctAnswer2.classList.remove('hidden2');
   } else {
    correctAnswer2.classList.add('hidden2');
   }
  }
 });

Comment: @MbaliNtuli, I think you would have to at least try to understand why and post what you don't understand in another question

Comment: thank you very much